# Where to add the license file?

Tags: open-source

I have written an application in Python using Tkinter and want to distribute under the WTFPL license. But I don't understand where to add the copying.txt file that needs to be added in the folder that is distributed.

**Please** clarify.

Comment: Right next to your `readme.txt` (or `README.md` if it's a Github project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an archive copying.txt in your root folder with follow content:

```
            DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE
                    Version 2, December 2004

 Copyright (C) 2004 Sam Hocevar <sam@hocevar.net>

 Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim or modified
 copies of this license document, and changing it is allowed as long
 as the name is changed.

            DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE
   TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR COPYING, DISTRIBUTION AND MODIFICATION

  0. You just DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO.
```